# Fetching next row from access database in VS C# 2010

Tags: c#

I have tried the following code but it throws exception "No value given for one or more required parameters".

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data      
      Source=C:\Users\yogi\Documents\mydb.mdb";
      string cmdstr1 = "select count(*) from quant_level1";
      OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(constr);
      OleDbCommand com1 = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr1, con1);
      con1.Open();
      int count = (int) com1.ExecuteScalar();
      int i = 2;
      while (i <= count)
      {
           string cmdstr = "select * from quant_level1 where id = i";
           OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
           OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
           con.Open();
           OleDbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
           reader.Read();
           label1.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[1]);
           RadioButton1.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[2]);
           RadioButton2.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[3]);
           RadioButton3.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[4]);
           RadioButton4.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[5]);
           con.Close();
           i++;
      }
      con1.Close();
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I am trying to fetch next row of the database.

Comment: `RadioButton1.Text` would be assigned data from the last row in table.Is that what you want..Please make your question clear

Comment: No I want to fetch next row every time on clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is within the select Statement:
You are trying to select an ID which you don't provide.

```cs
 string cmdstr = "select * from quant_level1 where id = i";
```

Your select statement should look like:

```
string cmdstr = "select * from quant_level1 where id = " + i;
```

Your Loop-counter is/was within your string. It won't be replaced automatically.

Comment: No Problem - but you should clarify your question. Basically you're assign the last Table entry to your Controls - is that really what you want to do?

Comment: No I don't want that.I want to fetch next row on clicking the button every time.Please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: see Anirudh solution - this will do what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to fetch next row every time on clicking the button.

```
int i=2;
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data      
      Source=C:\Users\yogi\Documents\mydb.mdb";
      string cmdstr1 = "select * from quant_level1 where id ="+i;
      OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(constr);
      OleDbCommand com1 = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr1, con1);
      con1.Open();
      if(reader.Read())
      {
           label1.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[1]);
           RadioButton1.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[2]);
           RadioButton2.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[3]);
           RadioButton3.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[4]);
           RadioButton4.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[5]);
           i++;
      }
      con1.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

***work only if you are using Web Application***

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    if (ViewState["count"] != null)
        i = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"].ToString());
    else
        i = 2; // assuming that it is your starting point as given in question

    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\Users\yogi\Documents\mydb.mdb";
    string cmdstr1 = "select count(*) from quant_level1";
    OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand com1 = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr1, con1);
    con1.Open();
    int count = (int)com1.ExecuteScalar();

    if (i < count)
    {
        string cmdstr = "select * from quant_level1 where id = i";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        label1.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[1]);
        RadioButton1.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[2]);
        RadioButton2.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[3]);
        RadioButton3.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[4]);
        RadioButton4.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader[5]);
        con.Close();
        i++;
        ViewState["count"] = i.ToString();
    }
    con1.Close();
}
```

This will do the trick in your case. happy coding :)